# Issue taking photo

Tags: android, camera, photo

I have to implement a function that allow the user to take a photo, I need to force the screen orientation to portrait.

More android devices, in particular tablets, are equipped of a rear camera that is mounted on the top of the case (portrait mode), others devices instead are mouted on the side of the tablet (landscape mode).

For example:

- Huawei M2-A01L (camera on the side)
- Samsung Galaxy Tab A6 (camera on the top)

I need all the photos taken in portrait mode, the code below  is the one I implemented but not work.

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
        File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + PDF_FOLDER_C);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));                                                                  
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, idRow);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need all the photos taken in portrait mode

There is nothing with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` for you to force a particular orientation, for the hundreds (if not thousands) of camera apps that might be started with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

You are welcome to experiment with the native camera APIs (`android.hardware.Camera`, `android.hardware.camera2.*`) to see if you can get something like what you want. Bear in mind that the user is welcome to hold their device in whatever orientation that they want.

Comment: What interests me specifically is not how the user takes the picture (landscape or portrait) but how the device takes the picture.

The preview of the shot must always be in portrait mode, the image in output must be in portrait

Comment: @Max: That does not change my answer. There is nothing for this in `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Use the camera APIs directly. And be prepared to test on lots and lots of devices, as camera hardware often behaves strangely.